# QVBoxLayout minimumSize is wrong after addWidget

Tags: qt

When executing the following code, the minimumSize does not take the newly added label into account. The label is added after the window is shown in my code and the widget should resize accordingly. If I wait a couple of milliseconds (probably after the first paint occurs), the minimumSize is then correct but I want to resize "w" right after adding the new label...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* This application prints the following output:

label hint: 33x16
layout: 24x24
layout with label: 24x24
layout with label (activated): 24x24

And this comes out when the main_window->show() is executed last (this is correct):

label hint: 33x16
layout: 24x24
layout with label: 57x40
layout with label (activated): 57x40
*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QWidget *main_window = new QWidget();

 QWidget* w= new QWidget(main_window);
 w->move(20,20);

 QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(w);
 // When this happens *after* widgets are added, the sizes are OK.
 // When we show the main window before, the sizes are wrong. Why ?
 main_window->show();

 QLabel *lbl = new QLabel("Hello");
 QSize sz = lbl->sizeHint();
 printf("label hint: %ix%i\n", sz.width(), sz.height());

 sz = lay->minimumSize();

 printf("layout: %ix%i\n", sz.width(), sz.height());

 lay->addWidget(lbl);
 // resizing 'w' here does not work because minimumSize is wrong...
 // w->resize(lay->minimumSize());     

 sz = lay->minimumSize();
 printf("layout with label: %ix%i\n", sz.width(), sz.height());

 lay->activate();
 sz = lay->minimumSize();
 printf("layout with label (activated): %ix%i\n", sz.width(), sz.height());


 // layout and label sizes are OK if this is executed here.
 //main_window->show();
 return app.exec();
}
```

Main window when I show() before adding labels:

http://lubyk.org/en/image394_std.png?661680336517

And the same thing when show() appears last:

http://lubyk.org/en/image395_std.png?661680336526

The real use case is some kind of "tools" widget displaying remote processes on the network in lubyk. These processes come and go. If I use QHBoxLayout and but the machine list inside, it uses all vertical space which is a waste (and ugly). By having a floating widget, it can be transparent (looks pretty) and we can use the space below.

Bug when a process appears:

http://lubyk.org/en/image392_std.png?661680334428

Correct drawing (I resized the main window to force the resizing and size update):

http://lubyk.org/en/image393_std.png?661680334439

PS: "gaspard" is the hostname of my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
lay->addWidget(lbl);
lbl->show();
main_window->update();
```

Comment: `lbl->show()` was exactly what I missed in my code. Thanks for helping.

Comment: lbl->show(); So simple! No examples include this, is it not always explicitly needed?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... this is a weird problem. I stepped through the code and the reason that the sizes are off is that the `QLabel` is considered not visible. If you add `lbl->setVisible(true)` after adding your label to the layout, the sizes are the same.

That said, the resulting display still didn't look quite right, but maybe this at least gets you one step closer?

Also, is the following code accomplishing what you are ultimately trying to achieve?

```
#include <QtGui>

class ToolWindow : public QDialog {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ToolWindow(QWidget *parent = NULL) : QDialog(parent, Qt::Tool) {
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    setLayout(layout);
  }
public slots:
  void addButton() {
    layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton("Hello, world"));
  }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QMainWindow main_window;
  ToolWindow tool_window;

  QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Push Me!");
  button->connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &tool_window, SLOT(addButton()));

  main_window.setCentralWidget(button);

  main_window.show();
  tool_window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help... The visibility problem was exactly what was causing the troubles. Simply adding `lbl->show()` after adding the widget solved my issue.